AWS .NET 8 Lambda reads appsettings.json when run locally on my machine, but not when deployed
I have an AWS Lambda that was built as a .NET 8 Minimal API using AWS.Lambda.PowerTools.  The function works perfectly when I run it locally in Visual Studio 2022.  It's able to read my appsettings.{environment}.json file and execute the function accordingly.
But the reading of the appsettings doesn't appear to be happening after I've deployed it to my AWS account and executed it via the URL.
Here's what the config initialization code looks like in my app:
var netEnv = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
Logger.LogInformation($"Using .NET environment '{netEnv}'...");

IConfigurationBuilder configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile(Constants.RootAppSettingsFile, false, true)
    .AddJsonFile(string.Format("appsettings.{0}.json", netEnv), false, true);
IConfigurationRoot config = configBuilder.Build();

The resulting CloudWatch log verifies that netEnv is being set to "Development", as expected.  Thus, appsettings.{0}.json is resolving to appsettings.Development.json as expected.
I've also downloaded the app code zip directly from the Lambda hosted in my AWS account and verified that appsettings.Development.json is at the root of the folder (at the same level as my app's binaries) - as well as verifying that this appsettings.Development.json is populated with the right values.
However, in my code, after the config setup, if I serialize and log the contents of config to CloudWatch as follows:
Logger.LogInformation($"using config '{JsonSerializer.Serialize(config)}'");
Instead of seeing the contents of config (i.e. what's in my appsettings file), I merely see this:
{
    "timestamp": "2024-05-22T15:29:10.2626946Z",
    "level": "Information",
    "service": "service_undefined",
    "name": "AWS.Lambda.Powertools.Logging.Logger",
    "message": "using config '{\"Providers\":[{},{}]}'"
}

Basically, the hosted app thinks that the only thing in config is {\"Providers\":[{},{}]}.
Why is it not reading my config data?
(Btw, as an added debugging step, I also logged the output of Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().  Instead of logging a string indicating my app's current directory, it merely shows "{}".
Why is this happening?  What do I need to fix to ensure that the deployed Lambda reads the appsettings file?

Why do you need to deploy ASP.NET Web API into AWS Lambda? is it your legacy code ? or new one ? it is not recommended to deploy ASP.NET into Lambda

What this code is prining in Logs Logger.LogInformation($"Using .NET environment '{netEnv}'...");  ??? Check environment variables in your Lambda function. I think you don't have ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in your environment variables

@SergeyK regarding your first question, this is my new code following the guidelines here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-net-6-runtime-for-aws-lambda/ - particularly 2/3 through under the heading "ASP.NET Core minimal APIs".  This makes the case for deploying a Lambda as a .NET Minimal API.
Regarding your second question: I already mentioned in my post that Logger.LogInformation($"Using .NET environment '{netEnv}'...") outputs "Using .NET environment 'Development'..." in the logs.

Perhaps the file path is case sensitive? Should it be "appsettings.development.json"

@CB_at_Sw the support of deploying ASP.NET Minimal or other API in AWS Lambda just to migrate legacy systems, I do not recommend this approach for new APS you should use AWS Lambda as it is without ASP.NET! and check my answer

You can use something like "Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location". It will give you the path of the assembly with the entry point.

I believe you didn't set Environment variable for your lambda function
var netEnv = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"); 

this code will not print nothing in logs
you need to add environment variable to your Lambda function with the name "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" and then you can access it.
you can add it in your SAM template for more info please look at AWS Lambda Documentation
Another thing is that AWS Lambda is in Linux where the all paths is case sensitive

This is not the issue.  The Lambda is already set up with the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable, and I have verified vla logging that netEnv is getting set to "Development" when the function executes in AWS.  So the problem is something else.

@CB_at_Sw check this (Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) print in logs it could be problem with path, and check where is settings.json file is located in AWS package it could be not in the same location as localy because of publish package command
